# Making a ComboBox Selection Control Visibility/Non Visibility of Shapes Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, combobox, powerpoint, shapes

I have a simple ComboBox in a slide with values added as follows:

```
0 = 2018 Pinot Noir
1 = 2019 Pinot Noir
2 = 2020 Pinot Noir
```

I now want the user selection to control whether the image (shape) in Powerpoint is visible or not. So I thought a simple case statement on the ComboBox1_Change event would be sufficient. However, I then realised I would probably have to **assign** the above values to the name of the images in the slide. These names are **identical** to the ComboBox values.

I've done this before but I am sure I'm missing an object of Powerpoint to achieve this.  So far the code is:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()
    If ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then AddDropDownItems
End Sub

Sub AddDropDownItems()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "2018 Pinot Noir"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "2019 Pinot Noir"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "2020 Pinot Noir"
    ComboBox1.ListRows = 3
    'ComboBox1.Clear
End Sub

Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim imgPinot As Shape
    Dim imgPinot2 As Shape
    Dim imgPinot3 As Shape


    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
        Case 0
            imgPinot.Visible = True
            imgPinot2.Visible = False
            imgPinot3.Visible = False
        Case 1
            imgPinot.Visible = False
            imgPinot2.Visible = True
            imgPinot3.Visible = False
        Case 2
            imgPinot.Visible = False
            imgPinot2.Visible = False
            imgPinot3.Visible = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

The other thing I want to control is that once the user has finished the selection, the Index of the Combo Box is reset.

I feel a little foolish not being able to do this.  Must be getting to old! Please assist if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if your image names match your combobox entries

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()
    If ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then AddDropDownItems
End Sub

Sub AddDropDownItems()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "2018 Pinot Noir"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "2019 Pinot Noir"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "2020 Pinot Noir"
    ComboBox1.ListRows = 3
End Sub

Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim sel, n As Long, cb As ComboBox, nm
    
    Set cb = Me.ComboBox1
    sel = cb.Value                         'selected item
    'loop over list 
    For n = 1 To cb.ListCount
        nm = cb.List(n - 1)                'list entry
        Me.Shapes(nm).Visible = (nm = sel) 'show only if entry matches selection
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is efficient way of looping through the images.

Answer (score 0):

**ComboBox1.Value** contains the text (i.e. 2018 Pinot Noir), not the list index. You also have to refer back to the presentation for the code to turn images on and off. imgPinot.Visible would only work if the image was on the UserForm.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()
    If ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then AddDropDownItems
End Sub

Sub AddDropDownItems()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "2018 Pinot Noir"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "2019 Pinot Noir"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "2020 Pinot Noir"
    ComboBox1.ListRows = 3
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim imgPinot As Shape
    Dim imgPinot2 As Shape
    Dim imgPinot3 As Shape

    Select Case ComboBox1.ListIndex
        Case 0
            With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
                .Shapes("imgPinot").Visible = True
                .Shapes("imgPinot2").Visible = False
                .Shapes("imgPinot3").Visible = False
            End With
        Case 1
            With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
                .Shapes("imgPinot").Visible = False
                .Shapes("imgPinot2").Visible = True
                .Shapes("imgPinot3").Visible = False
            End With
        Case 2
            With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
                .Shapes("imgPinot").Visible = False
                .Shapes("imgPinot2").Visible = False
                .Shapes("imgPinot3").Visible = True
            End With
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code and sure it works on a form but I didn't want to use one because I felt **IF** there is a control in Powerpoint under Selection Pane to manually turn an image/shape etc.on or off, surely there must be a method to do the same in code and to assign the Selection to a ComboBox....I guess not.  Maybe I am doing too much for my presentation.

Comment: From your comments, I gather you are using an ActiveX control, which you didn't mention in your post. The same code runs in the control, I've revised my listing, please try it again.

Comment: Thanks for giving me another solution. I've gone with @TimWilliams but I will definitely try out yours again.